# How to Download Photo Album,s from Picasa or Flickr using iPhone SDK...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flickr, picasa

I am trying to get the albums from Picasa or Flickr. I was unable found useful information from google. What exactly I needed is upon giving the login credentials, we need to download the albums and then display the images as albums in the Application.